# Worse training result by using experts code of TensorFlow 2.0 compared to beginner code

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I saw two quick start templates on tutorial of **TensorFlow 2.0.0 alpha**. One is for a beginner which uses `model.fit` for training and the other one uses with `tf.GradientTape() as tape:` and `optimizer`.

I tried both two code to train the same data, same network, but only beginner one works well.

**Input:**[224, 224] pictures * 240

**Network:**VGG19 on keras application

**Number of class:** 24

**Model:**

```py
vgg = VGG19(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights='imagenet')
vgg.trainable = True
for layer in vgg.layers[:17]:
    layer.trainable = False

model = models.Sequential([vgg, Dense(24, activation='softmax')])
```

**Beginners code:**

```py
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=base_learning_rate), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=total_epochs, batch_size=4)
```

**Experts code:**

```py
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(base_learning_rate)
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')


@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(images)
        loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    # gradients = [tf.clip_by_norm(g, 5) for g in gradients]
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(labels, predictions)


    x, y = read_data('Images')
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset = dataset.map(cast).repeat(total_epochs).shuffle(300).batch(4)
    for epoch in range(total_epochs):
        for image, label in dataset:
            train_step(image, label)

        template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}'
        print(template.format(epoch + 1,
                              train_loss.result(),
                              train_accuracy.result() * 100))
```

**Results of beginners:**

```
1/60 [..............................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 0.0631 - accuracy: 1.0000
2/60 [>.............................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 0.0440 - accuracy: 1.0000
3/60 [>.............................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.0340 - accuracy: 1.0000
4/60 [=>............................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.0274 - accuracy: 1.0000
5/60 [=>............................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.0307 - accuracy: 1.0000
6/60 [==>...........................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.0279 - accuracy: 1.0000
7/60 [==>...........................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.0261 - accuracy: 1.0000
8/60 [===>..........................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0315 - accuracy: 1.0000
9/60 [===>..........................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0293 - accuracy: 1.0000
10/60 [====>.........................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0272 - accuracy: 1.0000
11/60 [====>.........................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0300 - accuracy: 1.0000
12/60 [=====>........................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0446 - accuracy: 1.0000
13/60 [=====>........................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0416 - accuracy: 1.0000
14/60 [======>.......................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0440 - accuracy: 1.0000
15/60 [======>.......................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0439 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

**Results of experts:**

```
Epoch 1, Loss: 4.321621, Accuracy: 3.225641
Epoch 2, Loss: 3.671219, Accuracy: 4.160391
Epoch 3, Loss: 3.451912, Accuracy: 3.561214
```

Comment: what is `map(cast)` for? what is `cast`?? Please append this function to your question as well.

Comment: cast function convert the feature from tf.float64 type to tf.float32 type

Comment: Train for more epochs, 3 epochs is certainly not enough to conclude that there is a difference in performance. Difference in performance at the beginning of training is possible due to different weight initializations.

Comment: I tried more epochs, but it still keep low accuracy, never be higher than 5%. Plus, I used weights of imagenet, then fineturn the network and made only last few layer to be trainable. Turn as a result, only after one epoch, the beginner one already has reached almost 100% accuracy.

Comment: Except the training function, other configurations like weight initializations, network, training data, loss function and optimizer are all the same.

Comment: Ok, I’ll take a look again tomorrow.

Comment: I solve this problem today. It is due to I set 'softmax' function as activity function on the top layer while using 'categorical_crossentropy' loss. It is a really stupid mistake. Anyway, thank you very much!